# Receiving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate a validation plugin with a form in `Bootstrap`. When I use the code below, I get the following error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (".

I can't figure out whether the issue is with the PHP, the Javascript, or both. Is the PHP coded correctly here?

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#formBasic').formValidation({   
  framework: 'bootstrap',
  fields: {
    firstName: {
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'Name is required'
        }
      }
    },
    lastName: {
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'The password is required'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(e.target);
  var bv = $form.data('formValidation');

  $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
        error: function () {
          alert("There was an error processing this page.");
          return false;
        },
        success: function (output) {
          $('#formBasicResults').html(output.responseText);
          alert('success');
        }
      }, 'json');
  });
```

PHP:

```
function formBasic(){
$output = 'Output from Form Basic:
';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $output .= $key . ': ' . $value . '
';
}
echo $output;
}

if(in_array($_POST['function'], array('formBasic','formAdvanced'))){
$_POST['function']();
}else{
echo 'There was an error processing the form';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.post` syntax is incorrect where you are declaring the `success` and `error` handlers. Try this:

```
$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize())
    .done(function(result) {
        $('#formBasicResults').html(result.responseText);
        alert('success');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("There was an error processing this page.");
    });
```

Comment: Does this mean that there's no need to use json here?

Comment: @ken: well you can use `$.ajax` instead for ur purpose, only additional thing u need to include is the `type:post`.
`$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John" },
})`

Comment: @Ken this is still using JSON. jQuery will automatically determine the response type based on the content returned so you can omit the `'json'` setting.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I feel Ken need more control over the datatype he wants to access , in case he wants jsonp in future

Comment: You can still provide that parameter to `$.post`, I just removed it as it wasn't explicitly required in this case. Just FYI the downvote on your answer wasn't me by the way.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thank you. I'm no longer getting that error. I am now getting a Uncaught TypeError at the second line of the code above . . . but I suppose that's a question for another post.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : ha ha ha, i never thought jquery would determine the datatype of the response based on the returned MIME type . thanks for being prompt on the downvote thing :P

Comment: @ken: there is a missing comma `,` after done callback and before  fail callback.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the freedom to specify the datatype as `json` or `jsonp` or text using `$.ajax`

So instead of $.post use $.ajax, only additional thing you need to include is the `type:post`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    dataType: "json"
    data: { name: "John" },
    success:function () { //handle success calls},
    error:function () { //handle failure calls}
});
```

**REF:** http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/